# Parse.com IOS, cannot fetch a pointer to PFUser

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I am following the tutorials on Parse.com but I don't seem to get it working properly. Here is my issue.

I have a class called `Questions` and a class named `_User` of type PFUser (it has a picture icon next to the class name). User logins via FB and is registered as a `_User`. I can see myself in the `_User` class.

I make a question and I have a field in the `Question` class named `qOwner`, which is the owner of the Question. This is being set when saving a new question via the ios app like this :

```
QuestionCard[@"qOwner"] = [PFUser currentUser];
```

I can see the `objectId` of myself in `_User` to be the value inside the `qOwner` column, at the row for the current question made.

[image: _User class]

[image: Questions class]

Problem is that I cannot retrieve the values inside my app. If I place in the correct place the below:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Questions"];
[query addAscendingOrder:@"createdAt"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"@@@ : Successfully retrieved %lu questions ", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        NSLog(@"%@",objects);

        // fetched data are PFObjects
        // we need to convert that into a YesOrNo object
        // and then add it to _cards array

        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"currentUser : %@",[PFUser currentUser]);
            PFUser *qOwnerUser = [object objectForKey:@"qOwner"];
            NSLog(@"Question Made by : %@",qOwnerUser);
        }
.....
```

The following is being printed:

1)

```
@@@ : Successfully retrieved 1 cards
```

2)

```
(
        "<Questions: 0x17011f5c0, objectId: zZWGsfciEU, localId: (null)> {\n    CardId = 999;\n     qOwner = \"<PFUser: 0x17037e000, objectId: LtdxP5K0n6>\";\n    type = 0;\n  }"

)
```

3)

```
currentUser : <PFUser: 0x174375e40, objectId: LtdxP5K0n6, localId: (null)> {
    facebookId = 10153480462518901;
    thumbnail = "<PFFile: 0x174479a80>";
    username = UYRRmfbXDHqr1Ws4VwJcAy2wx;
}
```

4)

```
Question Made by : <PFUser: 0x17037e000, objectId: LtdxP5K0n6, localId: (null)> {
}
```

1-2-3 seem correct, I can see the pointer relation. But why in 4 inside `{}` I see nothing? I would have expected to see the same user details as in 3.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse does not fetch the pointer values by default in a query. You have to tell the query to include the pointer data using `includeKey:`. Do this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Questions"];
[query addAscendingOrder:@"createdAt"];
[query includeKey:@"qOwner"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```

Comment: Hmm I haven't noticed that in the documentation.. Thanks, i will try it once online and will accept the answer if correct!